# split a string of filenames from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table called products with a column (`images`)

there are many filenames in this column seperated by `[]` and `,`

like:

```
[image-1.jpg],[image-2.jpg],[image-4.jpg],[image-5.jpg]
```

and so on...

i want to be able to extract the images filenames so they look like:

```
image-1.jpg
image-2.jpg
image-3.jpg
image-4.jpg
image-5.jpg
```

here is my current PHP:

```
<?php
$images = explode(',',$project['images']);

        foreach($images as $image)
        {
            $display_image = substr($image, 1, -1);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="/img/project-gallery/<?php echo $display_image; ?>" width="160px" /><br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="current_images<?php echo $project["sequence"]; ?>" id="current_images<?php echo $project["sequence"]; ?>" value="image_id_checkbox_<?php echo $project["sequence"]; ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

so i have a checkbox under each image, which i want to be able to deleted the selected `[filename.extn],` from the images column in the database.

for example, if i check image-1.jpg checkbox i would want the images column to end up like:

```
image-2.jpg
image-3.jpg
image-4.jpg
image-5.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_split — Split string by a regular expression
This will do it...

```
$images = preg_split("/[\[\],]+/", $project['images']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
        $string = '[image-1.jpg],[image-2.jpg],[image-3.jpg],[image-4.jpg],[image-5.jpg]';
        $str_arr = explode(',', $string);

        foreach($str_arr as $key => $value)
        {
            $value = trim($value, '[]');
            echo $value."<br />";
        }
        ?>
```

--

Thanks ....

Comment: cool - do you know the best way to remove one filename from the images column - for example, if i have a checkbox next to each $value and whats checked will be removed from the database cell?

Comment: Yes, We can do this. What we need to do is get all the images which are checked by check box and then remove them from images column cell. Tell me if you need any help in code this.